# Uppercase letter & the if else laddder

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm novice to .NET in the below code i have written,first need to keyword convert it to upper case & after that If else ladder.Just check for correctness.here is my code,

```
 private string toupper(string keyword)
    {
        newkeyword = keyword.ToUpper();

        return newkeyword;
    }

    private string check(String newkeyword)
    {
        if (newkeyword == SETTELG || SETTHJORT)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx");
        }
        else if (newkeyword==SKUTTELG || SKUTTHJORT)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../SMSFunction/ShotSMS.ascx");
        }

        else if (newkeyword == RUNDBALL)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../SMSFunction/RoundballSMS.ascx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: A switch statement would be a valid alternative construct to use there. And your method doesn't return a value in any code path.

Comment: For correctness you need to first consult the compiler, then you could have posted here

Answer (score 2):

`StringDictionary` is case-insensitive, so you can avoid the upper/lower - so as a **field**:

```
readonly StringDictionary redirects = new StringDictionary {
    {SETTELG,    "../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx"},
    {SETTHJORT,  "../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx"},
    {SKUTTELG,   "../SMSFunction/ShotSMS.ascx"},
    {SKUTTHJORT, "../SMSFunction/ShotSMS.ascx"},
    {RUNDBALL,   "../SMSFunction/RoundballSMS.ascx"},
};
```

then just:

```
var path = redirects[keyword];
if(path != null) Response.Redirect(path);
```

Comment: Is `StringDictionary` preferable to a generic `Dictionary` with `StringComparer.xxxIgnoreCase`, or is there not much in it?

Comment: @rawling I suppose the only remaining consideration is the effective skill level of the OP, this uses dictionary initialisation syntax, which may also need explaining.

Comment: @Rawling only difference I can think of is whether you need it to implement `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` (which `StringDictionary` doesn't). Only reason I chose it was to avoid adding generics to the answer, in case that made it more complex.

Comment: @Marc Fair enough. I hadn't even come across `StringDictionary`, so something new learned today :)

Comment: @rawling System.Collections.Specialized if memory serves.

Comment: @Adam (on the subject on initialization syntax) - but, on the plus side, it is a *glorious* syntax for setting up this type of lookup in code ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh indeed, personally I would have done this a similar way too.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Check(string keyword)
    {
        switch(keyword.ToUpper())
        {
            case "SETTELG ":
            case  "SETTHJORT":
                Response.Redirect("../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx");
                break;
                /*remaining code*/
        }
    }
```

Make it as follows...

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to keywords and other (for the domain) well known string values I preferre to use some kind of parsing. In your particular case I would probably define an enum

```
public enum Keywords {
    SettleLG,
    SettHjort,
    SkutteLG,
    SkuttHjort,
    RundBall    
}
```

then you can parse the key words

```
//Note this will (deliberately) throw an exception 
//if the string does not match a defined value
//depending on your needs you might want to handle that
var parsedKeyword = (Keywords)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keywords),keyword,true);
```

With that in place you could then write a switch

```
private string GetRelativUrlFromKeyword(Keywords parsedKeyword){
    switch(parsedKeyword)
      case Keywords.SetteLG:
      case Keywords.SettHjort:
        return "../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx";
      case Keywords.SkutteLG:
      case Keywords.SkuttHjort:
        return "../SMSFunction/ShotSMS.ascx";
      case KeyWords.RundBall:
        return "../SMSFunction/RoundballSMS.ascx";
      default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Keyword not recognized" + parsedKeyword);
}
```

putting it all together your calling code would then look something like this

```
var parsedKeyword = (Keywords)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keywords),keyword);
var relativeUrl = GetRelativUrlFromKeyword(parsedKeyword);
Response.Redirect(relativeUrl,true);
```

By parsing the value as an enum you also validate the value (1), this will make it easier to hunt down bugs related to other parts of the code passing in incorrect values.
Switch constructs works fine if you want to have a hardcoded map between one set of values and another set of values as in your case between the keywords and the relative URLs.

I've split the mapping out in a separate function because it makes the code easier to reason about when each function/method does one thing.
The default case in the switch will throw an exception. This is to catch when you add a new keyword but forget to handle it in the switch. You could opt for other defaults. I generally like to throw exceptions in the default case when ending up there most likely is because I forgot to do something when changing other parts of the code. (2). I've also added a bool (true) to your response.redirect that tells the framework that you are done with the response and that it therefor can send it to the client (this is minor but I prefer to make my code as explicit as possible, when it comes to the intention of the code.)

(1) if you could get none keyword strings let me know and I can show how you'd use TryParse instead
(2) I would actualy like to have a compiler warning if I had left out a possible case value like I get if I have an incomplete pattern matching in F# but that's not necessarily possible for switchs (E.g. when using strings it's not)

Comment: To get the required case-insensitive behaviour you probably want `, false` on the `Enum.Parse` call

Comment: I'm really sorry - my bad, the parameter is `ignoreCase`, so should be `true`. Oops.

Comment: @MarcGravell lol I actually wrote `true`then changed to `false` then thought I should check it and then thought 'Nah it's marc he has his facts right' :p